# Creating layout for tablet and phone android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, hdpi

Ok, so, I have read a lot about creating layout for android devices. I thought I was on the right path when I wasnt. My situation is next:

I created layout-normal, layout-normal-land, layout-small, layout-small-land, etc... Then, I got values-normal-ldpi, values-normal-mdpi, and all the other qualifiers. I put the dimensions in those folders and in my layout, I use just them. Here is my layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarMainScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/visinaHeadera"
        android:background="#1d6cb5"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/senkaokoikonica"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/homeicon" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/razmakOdHomeDoTexta"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/marginaTextaZaIspisuHeaderu"
                android:text="Akcije i katalozi"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonOtvoriSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/search_klik"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/searchicon" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/razmakIzmedjuLupeIShare"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/shareButtonKataloziMainScreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/senkaokoikonica"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/shareicon" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/razmakIzmedjuLupeIShare"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/settingsButtonMainScreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/senkaokoikonica"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/settingsicon" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/razmakIzmedjuSettingsIDesnogKraja"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3.33dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarMainScreen"
        android:background="@drawable/headshad480" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3.33dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutZaSearchMainScreen"
        android:background="@drawable/headshad480"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutZaSearchMainScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/visinaDrugogHeadera"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarMainScreen"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbg">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextMainScreen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/editTextSearchVisina"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/editTextMarginaBot"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/editTextMarginaLeft"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/editTextMarginaRight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/editTextMarginaTop"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_conrer"
                android:hint="Pretraga"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/searchButtSearchVisina"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/searchButtMarginaBot"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/searchButtMarginaRight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/searchButtMarginaTop"
            android:background="@drawable/search_klik"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/searchiconkrug" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutZaReklameMainScreen"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarMainScreen"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonProdavci"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlikaIZida"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopZaGornjeSlike"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/prodavci"
                    android:scaleType="center" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonProizvodi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlikaIZida"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopZaGornjeSlike"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/proizvodi"
                    android:scaleType="center" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonBarkod"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlikaIZida"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlikaIZida"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/barcode"
                    android:scaleType="center" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSviKatalozi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlikaIZida"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlikaIZida"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginIzmedjuSlika"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/svikatalozi"
                    android:scaleType="center" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutZaReklameMainScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center|bottom">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adViewMainScreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/aik_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lejoutZaTransparentonstMainScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarMainScreen"
        android:alpha=".35"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Still, when I test it on my device(Samsung Galaxy s2 plus) it looks very good. WHen I test it on Nexus 5, it doesnt look even close.

Any suggestions on how to create adequate number of layout for the best solution for phones and tablets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these layouts to support all screen sizes:

> layout  # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
>
> layout-sw600dp # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
>
> layout-sw720dp # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

Comment: just one more question. Should I store my dimensions in values folder for each density or?

Comment: Yes you can do that as defining values of dimensions for different densities will give you flexibility with your code. It will also provide reusability.

Comment: yeah, but, if i store from that ratio mdpi = 1, hdpi = 1.5, etc, doesnt the resolution of the phone matters?

Comment: you can do this way too

Comment: For layout-sw600dp how to create landscape?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html : check out the link, you will find more info

Comment: please let me know if i've to make 7 inch tablet (1280*800 resolution) app in ladscape mode , then should i prefer layout-sw600dp or layout-w600dp or layout-w600dp-land ?

Comment: @RamkeshYadav it is according to your requirement but layout-w600dp-land will be a good option.

Comment: @Aakash , Thanx for your answer , i exactly opted this.